# Averaging Binned Values

Tags: matlab

I have an `NxM` matrix where I am binning on the first column into `n` buckets.  What I would like to know is if I would like to take the average of all values in the secondary columns of my matrix is this possible.

So basically what I want is if I have a `2x1000` matrix where I bin on the data for the first column, I'd like to be able to average all values in each bin based on the second column of my matrix.

Perhaps a function exists that will easily allow me to do this.  I appreciate any input.

Comment: This is best done with accumarray. There have been a few similar questions asked, if you search for accumarray.

Comment: See, for example, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15440874/index-from-accumarray-with-max-min-matlab. Just substitute max with mean.